# Why is my Meteor API call throwing an exception?

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, http-get, http-error

I've got the following code (based on pages 242 and 243 from "[Meteor In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617292478)") to try to call an external API:

The Meteor method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  . . .
  'getTextAddrAsEmailAddr': function(phone) {
    this.unblock;
    var apiUrl = 'http://www.xminder.com/number.check.php?number=' + phone;
    var response = Meteor.wrapAsync(apiCall) (apiUrl);
    return response;
  }
});
```

The "dedicated function":

```
var apiCall = function (apiUrl, callback) {
  try {
    var response = HTTP.get(apiUrl).data;
    callback(null, response);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      var errorCode = error.response.data.code;
      var errorMessage = error.response.data.message;
    } else {
      var errorCode = 500;
      var errorMessage = 'Cannot access the API';
    }
    var myError = new Meteor.Error(errorCode, errorMessage);
    callback(myError, null);
  }
}
```

How I'm calling it (one Meteor method calling another):

```
Meteor.methods({
  'insertPerson': function(firstname, lastname, streetaddr1, streetaddr2, placename, stateorprov, zipcode, emailaddr, phone, notes) {
    console.log('insertPerson reached'); // TODO: Remove before deploying
    check(firstname, String);
    . . .
    console.log('phone is ' + phone);
    var textAddrAsEmailAddr = Meteor.call("getTextAddrAsEmailAddr", phone, function(error, result) {
      console.log("textAddrAsEmailAddr is " + textAddrAsEmailAddr);
      console.log(result);
    })
    console.log('textAddrAsEmailAddr is ' + textAddrAsEmailAddr);
    . . .
```

The (Chrome) browser console output:

```
reached addPerson.submit form
methods.js:29 insertPerson reached
methods.js:41 phone is 2624908739
debug.js:41 Exception in callback of async function Error: Cannot access the API [500]
    at apiCall (http://localhost:3000/app/both/methods.js?55690625ac0aa28550112db1c63d2b8912cc3410:30:19)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:195:23
    at Meteor.methods.getTextAddrAsEmailAddr (http://localhost:3000/app/both/methods.js?55690625ac0aa28550112db1c63d2b8912cc3410:82:45)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3911:25
    at _.extend.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:971:17)
    at _.extend.apply (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3902:54)
    at _.extend.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3780:17)
    at Meteor.methods.insertPerson (http://localhost:3000/app/both/methods.js?55690625ac0aa28550112db1c63d2b8912cc3410:52:38)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3911:25
    at _.extend.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:971:17)
methods.js:50 textAddrAsEmailAddr is undefined
methods.js:51 undefined
methods.js:53 textAddrAsEmailAddr is undefined
```

The command prompt output:

```
I20151024-07:23:43.999(-7)? insertPerson reached
I20151024-07:23:44.021(-7)? phone is 2624908739
I20151024-07:23:44.641(-7)? textAddrAsEmailAddr is undefined
I20151024-07:23:44.649(-7)? null
I20151024-07:23:44.649(-7)? textAddrAsEmailAddr is undefined
```

So the upshot is, the catch block of my dedicated functio is hit. Why? I can enter the ApiUrl (*http://www.xminder.com/number.check.php?number=2624908739*) directly into the browser and get the following result:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"number":"2624908739","status":"YES","carrier_name":"ATT Mobility","carrier_id":"","sms_address":"2624908739@txt.att.net","mms_address":"2624908739@mms.att.net"}}
```

I want the *sms_address* value, specifically; why is my attempt to access this response failing?

### UPDATE

I changed the code to this:

```
var apiCall = function (apiUrl, callback) {
  try {
    var response = HTTP.get(apiUrl).data;
    callback(null, response);
  }
  // catch (error) {
  //   if (error.response) {
  //     var errorCode = error.response.data.code;
  //     var errorMessage = error.response.data.message;
  //   }
  //   else {
  //     // var errorCode = 500;
  //     var errorCode = error.response.code;
  //     // var errorMessage = 'Cannot access the API';
  //     var errorMessage = error.response.message;
  //   }
  //   var myError = new Meteor.Error(errorCode, errorMessage);
  //   callback(myError, null);
  // }
  catch (error) { console.log(error) };
}
```

...and get the same thing in the command prompt console:

```
I20151024-08:14:57.413(-7)? insertPerson reached
I20151024-08:14:57.434(-7)? phone is 2624908741
I20151024-08:14:58.248(-7)? textAddrAsEmailAddr is undefined
I20151024-08:14:58.255(-7)? null
I20151024-08:14:58.264(-7)? textAddrAsEmailAddr is undefined
```

...and this in the browser console:

```
reached addPerson.submit form
methods.js:25 insertPerson reached
methods.js:37 phone is 2624908741
methods.js:20 Error: Can't make a blocking HTTP call from the client; callback required.(…)
methods.js:46 textAddrAsEmailAddr is undefined
methods.js:47 undefined
methods.js:49 textAddrAsEmailAddr is undefined
```

**NOTE:** I get the same when changing the catch block to:

```
catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
  callback(error, null);
};
```

### UPDATE 2

Trying to use this specific API may be a lost cause, anyway, because testing a bogus phone number in the browser emitted:

```
{"success":false,"error":"Too many requests during last 24h"}
```

### UPDATE 3

I moved the Meteor methods from the \both\ folder to the \server\ folder, but apparently to little avail. I get only this in the browser console:

```
reached addPerson.submit form
```

...and this (still/again) in the command prompt console:

```
I20151024-13:02:23.539(-7)? insertPerson reached
I20151024-13:02:23.563(-7)? phone is 2624908743
I20151024-13:02:24.399(-7)? textAddrAsEmailAddr is undefined
I20151024-13:02:24.409(-7)? null
I20151024-13:02:24.410(-7)? textAddrAsEmailAddr is undefined
```

...but Jeroen Peeter's code differs from what I've got, and I don't know just how to incorporate it into my existing code; he says:

```
HTTP.get(apiUrl, function (error, data){
    console.log( 'http.get ::', error, data);
});
```

...and I've got:

```
var apiCall = function (apiUrl, callback) {
  try {
    var response = HTTP.get(apiUrl).data;
    callback(null, response);
  }
  catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      var errorCode = error.response.data.code;
      var errorMessage = error.response.data.message;
    }
    else {
      var errorCode = error.response.code;
      var errorMessage = error.response.message;
    }
    var myError = new Meteor.Error(errorCode, errorMessage);
    callback(myError, null);
  }
```

...so where does his code fit in with my (non-working) code?

### UPDATE 4

After changing this:

```
var response = HTTP.get(apiUrl).data;
```

...to this:

```
var response = JSON.parse(HTTP.get(apiUrl).content;
```

...I get, in the command prompt console:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.windows.x86_32):
   server/methods.js:4:54: server/methods.js: Unexpected token (4:54)

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Line 4, char 54 is the final "t" in "content"...???

Comment: Why don't you log the error in your catch clause. Now you set the error code to be 500 yourself. There is no way for me to see what the actual error is. Please log the error and post it here.

Comment: OK, I don't know exactly how to do that, but will try by assigning error.response.code to errorCode and error.response.message to errorMessage.

Comment: Just do: .....  } catch (error) { console.log(error); .....  and update your question with the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something wrong with the way that you are using Meteor.wrapAsync to make an external API call.

Here's how I would do it (in ecmascript2015)

```
let wrappedGetTextAddrAsEmailAddr = Meteor.wrapAsync(function (phone, callback) {
  const apiUrl = `http://www.xminder.com/number.check.php?number=${phone}`;

  HTTP.get(apiUrl, callback);
});

Meteor.methods(
{
  // Call like: Meteor.call('insertPerson', {firstname: 'Bob', ...});
  insertPerson(personData) 
  {
    let textAddrAsEmailAddr;

    console.log('insertPerson reached'); // TODO: Remove before deploying
    check(personData, Object);
    check(personData.firstname, String);
    . . .
    console.log(`phone is ${phone}`);
    textAddrAsEmailAddr = wrappedGetTextAddrAsEmailAddr(personData.phone);
    console.log(`textAddrAsEmailAddr is ${textAddrAsEmailAddr}`);
    . . .
  }
});
```

Make sure you put all the code above in server folder or just wrap them with `if (Meteor.isServer) { ... }`

Comment: I tried those changes, but it still fails on the final "t" on this line:
    var response = JSON.parse(HTTP.get(apiUrl).content;

Comment: You don't need to use var response = JSON.parse(HTTP.get(apiUrl).content; anymore, the answer above is all you need to make the API call works

Comment: Is the solution working for you? I have tested it on my computer and the API call is working

Comment: No, I never got it to work, but it's a moot point for me, as mentioned, as the API will only accept so many requests in 24 hours. I'll take your word for it that it works, though, and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Even if you are exceeding the request limit for the API, it will still return some sort of response indicating that the API call is successfully made.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that HTTP.get is run from the client instead of the server. In that case blocking calls are not possible, hence the error message. You need to define a callback:

```
HTTP.get(apiUrl, function (error, data){
    console.log( 'http.get ::', error, data);
});
```

If you don't want to run this on the client (and I think you don't want that), you need to make sure that your methods are defined on the server.
Put the files in which you define the Meteor.methods in the `server` folder, or wrap all Meteor.methods with `if (Meteor.isServer) { ... }` to ensure the methods are only defined on the server.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) { 
    Meteor.methods({
    . . .
    'getTextAddrAsEmailAddr': function(phone) {
        this.unblock;
        var apiUrl = 'http://www.xminder.com/number.check.php?number=' + phone;
        var response = Meteor.wrapAsync(apiCall) (apiUrl);
        return response;
    }
});
```

Comment: OK, thanks; I moved it from both to server, and will try again later.

Comment: try `HTTP.get(apiUrl).content` instead of `.data`. Node (and Meteor) use the Content-Type headers to determine the data-type. In this case the content-type is text/html so it *won't* attempt to parse it as JSON, hence the `.data` is empty. If you are certain that the API always returns JSON do `JSON.parse(HTTP.get(apiUrl).content)`

Comment: Dude, your missing a closing parenthesis!! Do you even know how to program javascript? If not, do start learning that first. Also, I gave you the correct line including that parenthesis, so try harder at correctly copy-pasting. I have the feeling that this way you're wasting everyone's time!